# get picture from dynamic content python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the href of the picture from an url without using selenium

```
def():
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen('')
    except httplib.IncompleteRead, e:
        page = e.partial              
         response = BeautifulSoup(page)
         print response
         var = response.find("div", {"id":"il_m"}).find('p')
```

but i got None as a result.What should I do to ge the href ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get the link from an *anchor* tag with a *download* attribute:

```
In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
In [3]: import urllib2

In [4]: r = urllib2.urlopen('http://icecat.us/index.php/product/image_gallery?num=9010647&id=9409545&lang=us&imgrefurl=philips.com')    
In [5]: soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"html.parser")

In [6]: print(soup.select_one("p a[download]")["href"])
http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/9010647-Philips-_FP.jpg
```

You should also take note of the text *Images may be subject to copyright.*. on the page.

Comment: thanks for ur answer but i got this error  'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: How did you get the source and what version of bs4?

Comment: version 4.4.0 and what did u mean by how i'm getting the source ,

Comment: I updated using urllib2 and you can see it gets the href so what is in the source you get from urllib2 and what is the response code?  Also you could probably do with updating your bs4 version, it is over a year old.

Comment: I'm getting the source using urllib2 and I'm getting the same error 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' .I will try to update bs4

Comment: Well the only other possibility is that you are not getting the source back correctly due to some error

Comment: I have another question with the same url

Answer (score 0):

You're not targeting the right *p* tag:

1. First of all, you want to extract the href from `<a>` node and not `<p>`
2. The first `<p>` child element that is found is this one `<p class="il_r" id="url_domain" </p>`

What you could do is to target the 5th `<p>` element's `<a>` which is the image. One way of doing this is `var = response.find("div", id = "il_m").find_all('p')[4].find('a')`

Comment: Thanks for taking time writing your insight. What I meant by "wrong element" is that the p element does not have a useful link and you need to "walk down" to the a element. I agree that my slicing solution is a little brittle and yours is much more concise, you posted just before me and I didn't see your answer.

Comment: Well I posted almost 20 minutes before you so not exactly just before. The download attribute is unique to the page so a lot more reliable than trying to slice to find the correct p tag, there are multiple ways including using the `data-filename`  attribute  to get the href, all much better than slicing especially if the OP is scraping multiple pages as a different ordering or another p added would break your slicing approach.